# Running on EC2 using an instance profile using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to run Terraform on an AWS EC2 instance, which is setup with an instance profile.  However, Terraform doesn't seem to be implicitly using the Instance Profile and as such, I'm getting an "access denied" error whenever it tries to access my S3 remote state.

From the docs, I'm having trouble telling if, I am required to specify an AWS_METADATA_URL, or if there's anything else I'm explicitly required to do to make this work.

Per the Terraform docs:

> EC2 Role If you're running Terraform from an EC2 instance with IAM
>   Instance Profile using IAM Role, Terraform will just ask the metadata
>   API endpoint for credentials.
>
> This is a preferred approach over any other when running in EC2 as you
>   can avoid hard coding credentials. Instead these are leased on-the-fly
>   by Terraform which reduces the chance of leakage.
>
> You can provide the custom metadata API endpoint via the
>   AWS_METADATA_URL variable which expects the endpoint URL, including
>   the version, and defaults to http://169.254.169.254:80/latest

Here's an example of what I'm trying to run:

```
# main.tf

provider "aws" {
  region = "${var.region}"
}

terraform {
  backend "s3" {}
}

module "core" {
  // ....
}


# init .sh

terraform init -force-copy -input=false \
        -backend-config="bucket=$TERRAFORM_STATE_BUCKET" \
        -backend-config="key=$ENVIRONMENT/$SERVICE" \
        -backend-config="region=$REGION" \
        -upgrade=true

# AWS policy
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

#### UPDATE

It seems the s3 list-objects command is failing in Terraform, though my policies should be allowing this to go through

```
-----------------------------------------------------
2018/02/20 21:09:37 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Response s3/ListObjects Details:
---[ RESPONSE ]--------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/xml
Date: Tue, 20 Feb 2018 21:09:36 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
X-Amz-Id-2: OVK5E3d5R+Jgj3if5lxAXkwuERPZWsJNFJ7NeMYFbSrhQ/h4FfpV4z2mlgXFKT1Hg7lsqJ/jE6Q=
X-Amz-Request-Id: FE6B77C5C74BCFFF


-----------------------------------------------------
2018/02/20 21:09:37 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>FE6B77C5C74BCFFF</RequestId><HostId>OVK5E3d5R+Jgj3if5lxAXkwuERPZWsJNFJ7NeMYFbSrhQ/h4FfpV4z2mlgXFKT1Hg7lsqJ/jE6Q=</HostId></Error>
2018/02/20 21:09:37 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Validate Response s3/ListObjects failed, not retrying, error AccessDenied: Access Denied
    status code: 403, request id: FE6B77C5C74BCFFF, host id: OVK5E3d5R+Jgj3if5lxAXkwuERPZWsJNFJ7NeMYFbSrhQ/h4FfpV4z2mlgXFKT1Hg7lsqJ/jE6Q=
2018/02/20 21:09:37 [DEBUG] plugin: waiting for all plugin processes to complete...
[31mError inspecting state in "s3": AccessDenied: Access Denied
    status code: 403, request id: FE6B77C5C74BCFFF, host id: OVK5E3d5R+Jgj3if5lxAXkwuERPZWsJNFJ7NeMYFbSrhQ/h4FfpV4z2mlgXFKT1Hg7lsqJ/jE6Q=
```

Comment: You need an IAM policy with s3 access attached to your instance profile.

Comment: @SudharsanSivasankaran yes, i already have this setup

Comment: Can you post the policy? you don't need to mention the METADATA explicitly. Can you try to run "aws s3 ls"?  just to see if your instance profile is set up correctly.

Comment: @SudharsanSivasankaran yes, if i run `aws s3 ls` it does successfully print a list of my s3 buckets.  I'm attaching the policies above.  The only thing that may be unusual about mysetup:  I have 2 policies attached to my Role for my Profile.  I'm using `kops` and it sets a Policy with very specific `allow` statements.  I'm then attaching a second policy with wide-open `s3` permissions.

Comment: Can you share the error you get? Ideally the relevant API call when setting `TF_LOG=DEBUG` as well.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR updated with debug output

Comment: @ydaetskcoR it seems that the `list-objects` command for the terraform s3 bucket is failing, though im not sure why

Comment: Is the bucket definitely in the same account? If you are on the instance and use the AWS CLI can you get the object?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR yes the bucket is in the same account. Im running `terraform init` to initialize a new backend under a new key int he s3 bucket, so if i run `get-object` from the instance in the aws cli, i get a different error: `The specified key does not exist`

Comment: Just for sanity's sake it might be worth echoing the `TERRAFORM_STATE_BUCKET`, `ENVIRONMENT`, `SERVICE` and `REGION` environment variables in your init.sh script

Comment: @ydaetskcoR yeah they all seem accurate. Does terraform document anywhere what permissions it requires to work with remote state on s3?

Comment: Nope but you can see what's failing so that doesn't matter. What might help is to ditch the remote state for a bit and just try applying a small TF file with the `aws_caller_identity` data source and outputting the values from that.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR well i tried a test:  i ran the same script using a remote state that had already been setup, as well as this new one where im creating the remote state for the first time.  In the case of an existing state, everything worked fine.  So I compared the debug outputs:  For whatever reason, it seems that in setting up the new remote state, it's not using the bucket-name properly.  So when it tries to list objects, get objects, etc it's doing it at the /root level of my s3 account, and that seems to be why its encountering permissions issues.  I don't understand why it'd try to do this

Comment: @ydaetskcoR and if i run the same script on my localy machine with an AWS user that has the same set of policies, it works fine.  So that's a bit puzzling.  The only difference is: the remote one uses an instance profile, and the local one uses the aws cli "configure" to setup the credentials

Comment: @ydaetskcoR im not sure if its related, but i am running terraform from within a container on EC2.  Regardless, i've filed an issue in the Terraform git repo, in case there is in fact a bug: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/17423

Comment: And you're not running kube2iam or some other IAM proxying service on the instance? What's the network configuration on the pod/container?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR i'm not, but I setup up my cluster using kops (https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/iam_roles.md) and according to the docs: `Please note that currently all Pods running on your cluster have access to the instance IAM role.` So I would assume should have access to the permissions I need